# Brillouin Torus of graphene

Tags: solid-state-physics, crystals, graphene

I understand that the Brillouin Zone in a 2D momentum space is a torus if the corresponding edges that repeat are joined. What I cannot wrap around my head is how to do the same for the hexagonal BZ of Graphene? Which edges are to be joined to form a 2-Torus? Or should we consider the primitive unit cell of a parallelogram instead of the Wigner-Seitz cell?

Hope I could make my question clear enough.